# Getting variable from one page to another in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm a novice in react and I'm trying to use a variable from one page in another.

Here is the code the an currently working with:

TilbudSide.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import StartSide  from './StartSide';

function TilbudSide () {
  const [selectedCustomer, setSelectedCustomer] = useState(null);
  const [selectedCustomerNumber, setSelectedCustomerNumber] = useState(null);

  

  let apiUrlCostumers = null;
  const selectedCompany = StartSide().selectedCompany; // Access selectedCompany from StartSide
  console.log('SELECTEDCOMPANY '+ selectedCompany );
  if (selectedCompany === 'NOA') {
    apiUrlCostumers = 'http://localhost:8000/customers';
  };

  console.log(apiUrlCostumers)

return (  
      <div className="tilbud-side">
          <h2>Lag tilbud</h2>
      </div>
);
  
export default TilbudSide;
```

StartSide.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from './assets/NA_logo.svg';
import './StartSide.css';

function StartSide() {
    const [selectedCompany, setSelectedCompany] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate()


    const handleClickNOA = () => {
        setSelectedCompany('NOA'); 
        navigate('/tilbudside');
        // Perform any additional logic or actions upon clicking the icon
    };

    console.log(selectedCompany);

    return (
        
        <div onClick={handleClickNOA} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
            <img src={logo} className="NA-logo" alt="NA Logo" />
        </div>
    );
}

export default StartSide;
```

Everytime try to run TilbudSide.js the console log for apiUrlCostumers is always null and selectedCompany is always null. I dont understand why selectedCostumer doesn't change in StartSide.js  handleClickNOA(). Please help me.

Comment: You can't access properties on other components in this way `StartSide().selectedCompany`. If you need a value from a parent component, pass it as a prop to the child, if you need a value in a sibling, raise state up to a shared ancestor or use context. Also declaring variables at the top level of a component is almost never what you want; they will be redeclared every render and any logic also at the top level will also be reevaluated. Put them in state or use a ref.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to change a little bit the state handling, because I think there are easier approaches and cleaner.

You can use following approaches to handle state in your app:

1. Store - it stores the global state. Libraries like zustand or redux helps you to achieve that,
2. Contexts - a little more complex but native. Why stores are better? Because you can easily create very memory-heavy app using contexts, and if used with multiple children changing the state, you should also take care of re-rendering cycle using `useMemo` and `useCallback`. Still - let's you to share the state between components and pass it deeply (learn about `props drilling`)

Answer (score -1):

Your attempt to retrieve the selectedCompany variable from StartSide in the TilbudSide component is where the problem in your code lies. Right now, you are attempting to directly access the state of StartSide as a component. You should consider creating a different method that returns the chosen business value, though.

TilbudSide.js:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StartSide } from './StartSide'; // Import the StartSide function instead of component

function TilbudSide() {
  const [selectedCustomer, setSelectedCustomer] = useState(null);
  const [selectedCustomerNumber, setSelectedCustomerNumber] = useState(null);

  const selectedCompany = StartSide().selectedCompany; // Call the StartSide function to get the selectedCompany value

  let apiUrlCustomers = null;
  if (selectedCompany === 'NOA') {
    apiUrlCustomers = 'http://localhost:8000/customers';
  }

  console.log('SELECTEDCOMPANY: ' + selectedCompany);
  console.log(apiUrlCustomers);

  return (
    <div className="tilbud-side">
      <h2>Lag tilbud</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TilbudSide;
```

startside.js:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from './assets/NA_logo.svg';
import './StartSide.css';

export function StartSide() { // Export StartSide as a function instead of component
  const [selectedCompany, setSelectedCompany] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClickNOA = () => {
    setSelectedCompany('NOA'); 
    navigate('/tilbudside');
    // Perform any additional logic or actions upon clicking the icon
  };

  console.log(selectedCompany);

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClickNOA} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
      <img src={logo} className="NA-logo" alt="NA Logo" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

By exporting **StartSide** as a function and calling it to retrieve the selectedCompany value, you can access it correctly in the TilbudSide component.